# Cannot access protected symbol?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, protected

I'm getting

> cannot access protected symbol TParent.Test

for following code:

In Unit1:

```
TParent = class
protected
  function Test: TParent;
end;

implementation

function TParent.Test: TParent;
begin
  Result := Self
end;
```

In Unit2:

```
uses Unit1;

type

TChild = class(TParent)
end;

implementation

var c: TChild;
begin
  c := TChild.Create;
  c.Test.Test
end;
```

Shouldn't the return value be accessible to TChild?

```
c.Test;
c.Test
```

works, of course.

Comment: I reverted your edit. Your edit changed the question. That's not right after you've had two answers to your perfectly good question.

Comment: And now I reverted. Please don't change your question after you got answers, it invalidates the work the users have put into them. If you have a follow-up question, ask a new one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The return value *is* accessible to TChild, but what you are trying to do is access it through a TParent within the TChild which is subtly different.

Think of it this way.

c.Test is a TParent, yes?

Now imagine that you had a TParent defined like this

```
var 
  c: TChild;
  p: TParent
begin
  c := TChild.Create;
  p := c.Test;
  p.Test;
end;
```

which is exactly equivalent to your code. Should p be able to access Test? No, because it is protected (and in a different unit).

Comment: I had oversimplified (reduced) the code to show the problem. Now changed it to be inside a method of the child class. Same problem.

Comment: Same reason. Same substitution of type TParent within your function will illustrate the problem.

Answer (score 4):

```
var 
  c: TChild;
....
c.Test.Test;
```

The method `TParent.Test` is protected which means that it is accessible in methods of `TParent` and methods of classes derived from `TParent`. And, in addition, it is accessible when called on a reference whose class was defined in the same unit as the calling code.

The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Classes_and_Objects_(Delphi)#Private.2C_Protected.2C_and_Public_Members) says it like this, with my emphasis:

> A protected member is visible *anywhere in the module where its class is declared* and from any descendent class, regardless of the module where the descendent class appears.

The fact that `TChild` was declared in the unit where you access the protected member is the key to understanding this.

In your example code, in `Unit2` when you write `c.Test`, that call to `Test` is not made from a method of `TParent` or a class derived from it. But it is made on a variable of type `TChild`, which is declared in `Unit2`, the unit where the call to the method is made. And so it is visible.

However, `c.Test` is of type `TParent`. And because `TParent` is defined in a different unit, `Unit1`, `c.Test.Test` does not compile. Likewise this code would not compile in `Unit2`:

```
var
  p: TParent;
....
p.Test;
```

Comment: I had oversimplified (reduced) the code to show the problem. Now changed it to be inside a method of the child class. Shouldn't the TParent result be visible from a method inside an inherited class? Maybe I'm just missing something.

Comment: That's a different question. I reverted the edit. But even so, the answer to that other question is much the same.

Comment: My apologies. I wanted to keep the example as short as possible, but I had inadvertently changed the entire situation.

Comment: You reverted the edit? But that original question was an oversimplified code example of a different real case. Now it's worthless. And my editing work thrown out...

Comment: That's tough. It was your mistake. You should pay, not us. We spent time writing an answer to a perfectly good question, in good faith. Why should we be penalised for your mistake? It's no problem, you can just ask another question. However, you don't need to. It is just a minor variant on what is here right now.

Comment: Yes, that's what I did. I just had to revert to copy/paste my new version from the first question. Sorry for all the inconvenience caused.

Comment: I closed that one as a duplicate. It's just the same as what we have here. Look at the final block of code in my answer above. That is precisely the scenario you have in your duplicate.